How to Make Popover Dialog Move with AR Model?
How to Make Popover Dialog Move with AR Model?
I'm working on an AR plugin. I've implemented a feature where a pop-up appears when a part of the AR model is tapped. When I click on a specific part, I call the function:
showInfoPopup(partName: partName, targetPoint: location, modelTitle: partName)
In this function, I use the following code to generate a pop-up:

popOver = PopOver(targetPoint: targetPoint, topEdgeY: topEdgeY, leftEdgeX: leftEdgeX, rightEdgeX: rightEdgeX, bottomEdgeY: bottomEdgeY, title: title, content: content)

if isPopupAllowed == true {
    if let popOver = popOver {
        arView.addSubview(popOver)
    }
    isPopupAllowed = false
    print("add popover is not allowed")
}

The PopOver is a custom UIView class (code is provided at the end of this post).
Problem:
I want my pop-up dialog to move along with the AR model as I move my phone. I've tried a couple of approaches to update the pop-up position, but they only make the pop-up flicker briefly after the tap, and then it disappears.
Attempts:

Using transform:

if let popOver = popOver {
    popOver.isHidden = false
    let deltaX = screenPoint.x - CGFloat(targetPoint.x)
    let deltaY = screenPoint.y - CGFloat(targetPoint.y)
    popOver.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: deltaX, y: deltaY)
}


Updating Frame:

if let popOver = popOver {
    var newFrame = popOver.frame
    let deltaX = screenPoint.x - CGFloat(targetPoint.x)
    let deltaY = screenPoint.y - CGFloat(targetPoint.y)
    newFrame.origin.x += deltaX
    newFrame.origin.y += deltaY
    popOver.frame = newFrame
}

The result for both approaches is that the popover just flickers once after tapping and then disappears.
Render Loop and Updating Popover Position:
Here is the framework of my render loop and how I update the popover position:
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateOverlayPosition()
        self.updatePopOver(xRatio: self.xRatio, yRatio: self.yRatio, targetPoint: self.targetPoint)
    }
}

@objc func updatePopOver(xRatio: Float, yRatio: Float, targetPoint: CGPoint) {
    guard let modelNode = modelNode else { return }
    
    // Get model's bounding box and calculate the center point
    let min = modelNode.boundingBox.min
    let max = modelNode.boundingBox.max
    let targetPoint = SCNVector3(
        (min.x + max.x) / xRatio,
        (min.y + max.y) / yRatio,
        (min.z + max.z) / 2
    )
    
    // Convert the center point to world coordinates
    let worldTarget = modelNode.convertPosition(targetPoint, to: nil)
    
    // Convert the world coordinates to screen coordinates
    let projectedPoint = arView.projectPoint(worldTarget)
    
    // If the coordinate is on-screen, update the popover's position
    if projectedPoint.z > 0 {
        let screenPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(projectedPoint.x), y: CGFloat(projectedPoint.y))
        popOver?.isHidden = false
        // TODO: update popover's position
    } else {
        popOver?.isHidden = true
    }
}

PopOver Class:
Below is the PopOver class, which inherits from UIView:
import UIKit

class PopOver: UIView {
    // Initialization method with customizable content and style
    init(targetPoint: CGPoint,
         topEdgeY: CGFloat,
         leftEdgeX: CGFloat,
         rightEdgeX: CGFloat,
         bottomEdgeY: CGFloat,
         lineLength: CGFloat = 200,
         circleRadius: CGFloat = 5.0,
         cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20.0,
         title: String,
         content: String,
         titleFont: UIFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25),
         contentFont: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
         titleColor: UIColor = UIColor(hex: "#6A6E74"),
         contentColor: UIColor = UIColor(hex: "#6A6E74"),
         lineColor: UIColor = .white,
         backgroundColor: UIColor = .white,
         borderColor: UIColor = .lightGray) {
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        setupDialogueBox(targetPoint: targetPoint,
                         topEdgeY: topEdgeY,
                         leftEdgeX: leftEdgeX,
                         rightEdgeX: rightEdgeX,
                         bottomEdgeY: bottomEdgeY,
                         lineLength: lineLength,
                         circleRadius: circleRadius,
                         cornerRadius: cornerRadius,
                         title: title,
                         content: content,
                         titleFont: titleFont,
                         contentFont: contentFont,
                         titleColor: titleColor,
                         contentColor: contentColor,
                         lineColor: lineColor,
                         backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                         borderColor: borderColor)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // (More implementation details...)

    private func setupDialogueBox(...) {
        // Implementation to set up the popover box
    }
}

Question:
How can I make my pop-up move together with the AR model as the camera moves?
The current issue is that the pop-up flickers and disappears. I need the pop-up to always be at the correct position relative to the model when the phone moves.
Would appreciate any advice or direction!
